# how to use this-command and last-command in tests?

Tags: commands, interactive

I have a usecase for `this-command` and `last-command`, because I'd like a double invocation of a command to behave differently (it's an indenter, FWIW).

Some manual interactive experiments suggest that invoking commands manually with `M-x` or key combinations set the `this-command` and cycle `last-command`, which can sometimes get confusing if the command has any `kill-*` behaviour in it. This is as expected.

However, when called from my ert tests, even if I invoke functions with `run-interactively`, `this-command` remains `nil`.

How can I make my scripted ert tests invoke commands so that `this-command` / `last-command` behave the same as when the user is entering those commands?

Comment: Perhaps start by readling (elisp) [Command Loop Info], if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfect, but `ert-simulate-command` from `ert-x` works fairly well.

> ert-simulate-command is a compiled Lisp function in ‘ert-x.el’.
>
> (ert-simulate-command COMMAND)
>
> Simulate calling COMMAND the way the Emacs command loop would call it.
>
> This effectively executes
>
> ```
> (apply (car COMMAND) (cdr COMMAND))
> ```
>
> and returns the same value, but additionally runs hooks like
>   ‘pre-command-hook’ and ‘post-command-hook’, and sets variables like
>   ‘this-command’ and ‘last-command’.
>
> COMMAND should be a list where the car is the command symbol and the
>   rest are arguments to the command.
>
> NOTE: Since the command is not called by ‘call-interactively’ test for
>   ‘called-interactively’ in the command will fail.